# Fetch posts from current week (Sunday to Saturday)

Tags: posts, wp-query, date

I'm trying to fetch posts from current week.

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'year' => date( 'Y' ),
                 'week' => date( 'W' ),
            ),
        ),
        'post_type' => 'stars', 'posts_per_page' => 99, 'order' => 'DEC',
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

This code is fetching the posts from **Monday to Sunday** (Start day of my week is "Monday" in general settings.)
But when I changed the start date of week to "**Sunday**" in the general settings, the above code is not fetching any posts.

I referred to [this codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) and it leads me to [this MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week). But I'm not sure how to implement that in my query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'year' => date( 'Y' ),
        'week' => strftime( '%U' ),
    ),
 ),
```

where [`%U`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) is:

> Week number of the given year, starting with the first Sunday as the
> first week

or

```
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'after' => strtotime( 'last Sunday' ),
    ),
 ),
```

Comment: PERFECT !!! `'week' => strftime( '%U' ),` worked!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because a new week has been started and WordPress is trying to get posts from last Sunday (which was yesterday) to Saturday.

If you only want last week's post then Why don't you try to fetch last 7 days post instead. Like this.

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
            'after' => '7 days ago'
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'stars',
    'posts_per_page' => '99',
    'order' => 'DEC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);

$new_query = new WP_Query ( $args );
```

Comment: Robert, instead of last 7 day's post, I just need posts from current week only, starting from Sunday. For example, if i'm fetching the code today,it should show posts on yesterday and today only. If I'm running the code on "thursday", it should show posts from Sunday to Thursday.

Comment: So did you check if there are any posts made from this Sunday?

Comment: Yes, I have posts on Sunday and Monday. When the "start of week" settings is on "Monday", it shows the post on Monday(today). But when I change it to "Sunday", no posts are showing.

Comment: In that case, I am not sure what is the issue here. I will let someone else help you on this. :)

Comment: Thanks for trying Robert. I'm stuck with this for last 2 weeks.